# Ошибка в логике?

Tags: c++

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define O_F_NAME "output.txt"

int main()
{
                                                /* Variables */
    char need, it;
    char f_name[80];
    ios::pos_type pos;
    int min_num = 0, max_num, i = 1;

                                                /* Introduction */

    cout << "Enter the file: ";
    cin.get(f_name, 80);

    ifstream in(f_name, ios::in);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Error in opening file.\n\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\nEnter symbol for find: ";
    cin >> need;

    ofstream out(O_F_NAME, ios::out); 
    if (!out) {
        cout << "Error in creating output file.\n\n";
        exit(2);
    }
                                                /* Make head of output file */

    out << "Result of searching for \"" << need << "\":\n\n";

                                                /* Find max number of symbol */

    in.seekg(0, ios::end);
    pos = in.tellg();
    max_num = (int)pos - 1; // pos - number of end  
    in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

                                                /* Find 'it', write out to the file */

    while (!in.eof()) {
        it = (char)in.peek(); // ios::cur++
        if (it != need) {
            it = (char)in.get();
            continue;
        }
        out << i++ << ") '";
        pos = in.tellg(); // cur number
        if ((int)pos > min_num) {
            in.seekg(-1, ios::cur);
            out << (char)in.get();
        }
        out << (char)in.get();
        if (in.eof()) continue;
        if ((int)pos < max_num) {
            out << (char)in.get();
        }
        out << "'\n";
    }

    cout << "\nSuccess. Results of searching placed in \"" << O_F_NAME << "\"\n\n";

    out.close();
    in.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как справедливо заметили, я не указал, что хочу видеть на выходе:) Должно быть так: `[x][need][y]` - где `x` - символ слева от искомого, `y` - справа(если `need` первый или последний символ в файле, то "обрамление" опускается).
Если `need` = `-`(ищим тире) вывод программы(применил на книгу: [book.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mELZk8bPugLU80MVlVSy1aX28/view?usp=sharing)) примерно такой:

```
1) 'tor'
2) 'f-t'
3) 'f-t'
4) 'h-d'
5) 'h-d'
6) 'n-k'
7) '-te'
8) 'f-c'
9) 's.
'
...
```

(Откуда, например, взялась строка `1) 'tor'` если искали `-`?)

Мне казалось алгоритм исключает обрабатывание всех символов кроме нужного здесь:

```
        it = (char)in.peek(); // ios::cur++
        if (it != need) {
            it = (char)in.get();
            continue;
        }
```

Программа должна искать символ, который задаёт пользователь, в файле, который он вводит. Она работает, но странно(выводит неожиданные "три символа"). На маленьких(созданных вручную) файлах всё нормально, но на книге даёт такой вывод(смотрите выше). Не могу понять, чем это может быть обусловлено?

Comment: Отладчик и внятное описание что же программа должна делать, вероятно, вам помогут.

Comment: Вы не могли бы (1) оставить только минимальный для понимания вопроса код, (2) объяснить, что именно вы хотите, чтобы этот код делал?

Comment: @VlaD , программа должна искать символ, который задаёт пользователь, в файле, который вводит пользователь. Программа работает, но странно. На маленьких(созданных вручную) файлах всё нормально, но на книге даёт такой вот вывод(смотрите выше). Я не могу понять, чем это может быть обусловлено. Я думал, 70 строчек не так много, тем более, половина этого - алгоритм поиска, а вторая - простой(на сколько я понимаю) книжный код открытия потоков

Comment: @DimTeam задумайтесь о том, что описание ожидаемого поведения было бы неплохо внести в сам вопрос.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов внёс, посмотреть можете?

Comment: @DimTeam начните сами с использования отладчика.

Comment: Ну, книжный код наверное не нужен. Просто если при взгляде на простыню текста приходится ещё и думать, что из него относится к вопросу, а что нет, то не у всех хватает энтузиазма сесть и разобраться. Вот [немного нытья по этому поводу](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Вот это видели: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/421084/10105? Цикл `while (!eof())` неверен.

Comment: А ещё вы не контролируете ошибки, это неправильно, судя по всему.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за ответ, какие ошибки?

Comment: @VladD почитал вашу ссылку, я знаю, что `eof()` проверяет достижение конца файла после последней операции ввода/вывода, но я это учёл и проверяю посреди цикла `while`: `if (in.eof()) continue;`

Comment: @DimTeam: Прогнал ваш код на английской «Алисе в стране чудес», проблем не обнаружил. Выложите текст, на котором сбоит.

Comment: @DimTeam: Кстати, я бы всё же переписал ваш рабочий цикл так: http://pastebin.com/kRWF83Gx. Вы почему-то экономите на переменных, а экономить надо операции ввода-вывода, они на два порядка «тяжелее».

Comment: Во-первых, так и не смог понять, какой именно вывод Вы ожидаете получить от программы? Я прогнал ее на таком файле: 

asdkjnajn2-scbhjabschb-asdyyqwtd1-
aschhjuasd-sadfhwqed-

И получил:
Result of searching for "-":

1) '-sc'
2) '-as'
3) '-
a'
4) 'd-s'
5) 'd-'

Должно быть выведено обрамление искомого символа что ли?

Comment: @boeing777: Странно. У меня на том же тексте выдало 1) '2-s' 2) 'b-a' 3) '1- ' 4) 'd-s' 5) 'd-'.

Comment: @DimTeam: Вы должны проверять, выполнились ли файловые операции успешно. Для этого есть проверки типа `if (!in)` или `if (!in.good())`.

Comment: @boeing777 именно, должно быть "обрамление" искомого символа

Comment: @VladD добавил текст, на котором тестирую, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @VladD внедрил ваш переписанный цикл в свой код - всё работает отлично и как я хотел(с обрамлением). Спасибо большое, дело было в `seekg()?` Она в некоторых случаях неправильно перемещала указатель на `-1` символ?

Comment: @DimTeam: Если вы погуглите «problem with seekg», многие замечают, что если какая-то из операций не срабатывает (или если достигнут конец файла), с этого момента `seekg` не работает, пока не сбросить ошибку при помощи `in.clear()`. Может быть, в этом была ваша проблема. Оформлю код в ответ.

Comment: @VladD не спешите, он не совсем корректен) Я сейчас думаю, как его исправить. Попробуйте искать `-` в такой строке вашим циклом: `-qwer-` И спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не могу воспроизвести проблему у себя (Visual Studio 2013), но она может заключаться, например, в том, что `seekg` не работает, если поток находится в ошибочном состоянии или достиг конца файла (!). Для этого случая вы должны бы перед `seekg` вызвать `clear`.

Но я бы в любом случае переписал код по-другому: он избегает запоминания предыдущего символа, и из-за этого ему приходится манипулировать текущим указателем файла. Проще было бы просто закешировать предыдущие символы в переменных. Например, так (привожу только рабочий цикл):

```
int eofvalue = istream::traits_type::eof();
int curr = eofvalue, prev = eofvalue;
bool needExit = false;
while (!needExit)
{
    int prevprev = prev;
    prev = curr;
    curr = in.get();
    needExit = (curr == eofvalue);
    // не выходим сразу, прогоним ещё одну итерацию
    // для отлова искомого символа в финальной позиции

    if (prev != need)
        continue;

    cout << i++ << ") '";
    if (prevprev != eofvalue)
        cout << (char)prevprev;
    cout << (char)prev;
    if (curr != eofvalue)
        cout << (char)curr;
    cout << "'\n";
}
```

---

Ещё по вашему коду:

1. Цикл обработки `while (!in.eof())` [в общем случае неверен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/421084/10105). Даже если сейчас код правильно детектирует конец файла из-за особенностей обработки кода в цикле, небольшое изменение может сделать его неправильным.
2. Код `(char)in.peek()` и `(char)in.get()` также не очень хорош. Дело в том, что функция `get()` не зря возвращает не `char`, а больший тип: если достигнут конец файла, возвращается значение `istream::traits_type::eof()`, которое не попадает в тип `char`. При приведении типов вы теряете информацию о конце файла. Это особенно опасно в сочетании с предыдущей проблемой.

---

**Обновление**: Окей, новый код работает, а в чём же проблема исходного кода?

Если коротко: вы смешали произвольный доступ и построчную обработку, это не очень хорошо. Если вы хотите управлять позицией чтения через `tellg`/`seekg`, открывайте файл в бинарном режиме, это избавит вас от «сюриризов».

Подробное объяснение: Здесь замешано много вещей. Для начала, ваш файл имеет юниксовские концы строк (`\n`). Вы, судя по всему, работаете на Windows, где нативные концы строк имеют вид `\r\n`. Поскольку вы открываете файл в текстовом режиме (**без** `ios::binary`), то при построчном чтении происходит автоматическая трансляция строк в нативные строки: `\n` заменяется на `\r\n`. Это значит, что после того, как `in.get()` возвращает вам `\n`, рантайм начинает считать, что текущая позиция в файле увеличилась не на 1, а на 2, из-за неявно пропущенного `\r`.

Затем, что происходит при выполнении `seekg`? Позиция в файле устанавливается в новое значение. При этом для того, чтобы корректно пересчитать отличие номера байта в файле от его позиции в модифицированном потоке (в который неявно вставлены `\r` перед каждым `\n`), рантайму пришлось бы прочитать весь файл от той точки, где вы находитесь, до той точки, куда вы перемещаетесь. Это могло бы быть очень долго, поскольку вы имеете право сделать очень большой прыжок. Но `seekg` должно выполняться быстро, поэтому рантайм не заморачивается и сбрасывает подсчитанное отличие в 0.

Это приводит к тому, что `seekg` «промахивается» на столько байт, сколько раз встретился символ перевода строки в файле. Дальше цикл повторяется, с тем же результатом.

Если бы вы открыли файл в бинарном режиме (а раз вы его обрабатываете посимвольно, так надо и делать), проблема бы не возникла, так как в этом режиме трансляция строк не производится.

Comment: надо проверять failbit или включить эксепшены

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на 90% он верен. НО, если искать `-` в файле с таким содержимым: `-qwer-`, ваш код с треском проваливается, так как: `-1` - символ 'я'(cp1251) и заканчивается файл искомым символом(следующий - eof) - программа его не выводит. В результате её вывод будет таким: `1) 'я-q'` P.S. MVS 2013/Win7(русская)

Comment: Такой цикл меня устраивает, он верен? http://pastebin.com/NXu4RtFf

Comment: @DimTeam: подправил рабочий код, теперь работает. Сейчас гляну, что у вас там. // Посмотрел, так по идее тоже можно.

Comment: @DimTeam: Написал в ответе, в чём была причина неправильного поведения.

Comment: @VladD большое спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ. Я немного не понял здесь: `if (curr != -1) cout << (char)curr;`, почему именно `-1`?

Comment: @DimTeam: Это ошибка :-) Должно быть, конечно, `istream::traits_type::eof()`. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @VladD :-) не могли бы вы оставить какой-нибудь адрес(e-mail etc.)? Хотел бы развёрнуто вас отблагодарить, кое-что спросить, но это будет уже флуд

Comment: @DimTeam: Лучше всего пишите в C/C++-чат (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c), я там сижу.

Comment: Кстати, хотелось бы отметить, что переменная `need` должна быть объявлена именно как `char` - иначе `cin >> need` записывает символ не только в младший(вроде бы) из 4 байт

Comment: @DimTeam: Угу, именно так. Если `need` имело бы тип `int`, а пользователь ввёл бы `1`, то в результате присвоилось бы значение 1, а не `0х31 == '1'`. А `а` вообще бы не прочиталось (и увело бы `cin` в ошибочное состояние до явного сброса ошибки).

Comment: `int prevprev = prev` почему вы объявили `prevprev` именно в теле цикла?

Comment: @DimTeam: Потому что его _можно_ унести внутрь цикла, в отличие от остальных. Правило: старайтесь объявлять переменные в как можно более внутреннем блоке. И как можно ближе к месту первого использования.

Comment: Ясно, это вопрос удобства и стиля? И означает ли это, что на каждой итерации происходит "переобъявление" переменной `prevprev`?

Comment: @DimTeam: Угу, вопрос стиля. Это можно видеть как «переобъявление», но оптимизатор, конечно, выделит память заранее и один раз.

Comment: То бишь, по-сути, оптимизатор вынесет это объявление из цикла, но мне "визуально" удобнее так записывать?

Comment: И ещё, никак  не могу понять, почему сравнение `int` и `char`: `if (prev != need)` работает при разном размере переменных? `!=` - побитовый оператор, так с чем он сравнивает "остаток" переменной `prev`(int)? С нулями?

Comment: @DimTeam: Смотрите. Когда вы пишете код, вы пишете его как понятнее. Оптимизатор в любом случае гораздо лучше соптимизирует, чем и я и вы вручную, уж поверьте мне. Так что на оптимизацию, которая принесёт один несчастный такт процессорного времени, не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: Сравнение `int` с `char` работает так: определяется «наибольший общий тип» (`int`), оба сравниваемых элемента приводятся к этому типу (то есть, `char` расширяется до `int`'а), и сравниваются два `int`'а.

Answer (score 2):

Позволил себе переписать ваш код. На моём тесте сработало. Проверьте на вашей книге.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

#define O_F_NAME "output.txt"

int output(const char* txt, ofstream& out)
{
  static int count = 0;
  out << ++count <<  ") '" << txt << "'" << endl;
  return count;
}

int main()
{
                                                /* Variables */
  int start_pos = 0, end_pos = 0;
  char* str = 0;

  int need = 0, cur = 0;
  int count = 0;

  char f_name[80];
                                                /* Introduction */

    cout << "Enter the file: ";
    cin.get(f_name, 80);

    ifstream in(f_name, ios::in);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Error in opening file.\n\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    char tmp;
    cout << "\nEnter symbol for find: ";
    cin >> tmp;
    need = (int)tmp;
//    cout << ">>> need " << (char)need << " is " << tmp << endl;

    ofstream out(O_F_NAME, ios::out); 
    if (!out) {
        cout << "Error in creating output file.\n\n";
        exit(2);
    }
                                                /* Make head of output file */

    out << "Result of searching for \"" << need << "\":\n\n";

    if (!in.eof()) {
      cur = in.get();
//      cout << ">>>> cur " << (char)cur << endl;
      while (!in.eof()) {
        if (cur == need || in.peek() == need) {
          start_pos = in.tellg();
          start_pos -= 1;
//          cout << ">>> start_pos " << start_pos;
          cur = in.get();
          while (cur == need) {
            cur = in.get();
          }
          end_pos = in.tellg();
//          cout << " end_pos " << end_pos << endl;

          int length = end_pos - start_pos;
//          cout << "length " << length << endl;
          str = new char[length];
          in.seekg(start_pos);
          in.read(str, length);
//          cout << "str '" << str << "'" << endl;
          count = output(str, out);

          in.seekg(end_pos);

          delete[] str;
          str = 0;
        }
        else {
          cur = in.get();
        }
      }
    }

                                                /* Find max number of symbol */

    cout << "\nSuccess. Results of searching placed in \"" << O_F_NAME << "\" count = " << count << "\n\n";

    out.close();
    in.close();
//    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На моём не сработало: `Result of searching for "45":
1) 'torээээ««««««««юоюоюоюою'
2) 'f-tээээ««««««««юоюоюоюою' и так далее, добавил в пост книгу, на которой пробую

Comment: Даже там, где у моей версии всё хорошо выводится, ваша выдаёт кучу `<<<<<<<<<<<юююююююю` и так далее

Comment: @Dim Team , давайте разбираться по порядку. Я проверил код на вашей книге, вот результат [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B52xfyA50dHkUmkwb1JVSjg4T2s/view?usp=sharing). Книга предварительно переконвертирована в кодировку UTF-8. Код собирался на Debian Jessie, компилятор gcc 4.9.2. Проблема вероятнее всего кроется в несоответствии кодировок и, как вам выше уже написали, в окончании строк (\r - unix против \r\n - windows).

Comment: Кстати, вот [ваша книга](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B52xfyA50dHkLUNEX1REMGpWcmM/view?usp=sharing) в UTF-8, на которой я тестировал.

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо за помощь, отдельное @VladD. Теперь программа работает как надо. Возможно, кому-то пригодится её законченная версия:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define O_F_NAME "output.txt"

int main()
{
    char f_name[80], need;

    cout << "Enter the file: ";
    cin.get(f_name, 80);

    ifstream in(f_name, ios::in);
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Error in opening file.\n\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "\nEnter symbol for find: ";
    cin >> need;

    ofstream out(O_F_NAME, ios::out); 
    if (!out) {
        cout << "Error in creating output file.\n\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }

    out << "Result of searching for \"" << need << "\":\n\n";

// main cycle

    int i = 0, eofv = iostream::traits_type::eof();
    int prev = eofv, cur = eofv;
    bool needExit = false;

    while (!needExit) {
        int prevprev = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = in.get();

        needExit = (cur == eofv);

        if (prev != need) continue;

        out << ++i << ") '";
        if (prevprev != eofv) out << (char)prevprev;
        out << (char)prev;
        if (cur != eofv) out << (char)cur;
        out << "'\n";
    }

    cout << "\nSuccess. Found " << i << " matches.\n\n"
        << "Results of searching \"" << need << "\" in \"" << f_name
        << "\" placed in \"" << O_F_NAME << "\".\n\n";

    out.close();
    in.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```