# Проблема с потоком fstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здраствуйте, у меня проблема с потоком fstream. Точнее с считыванием файла. Программа просто зацикливается и больше ничего не делает.
Вот:

```
    #include <iostream>
    //#include "Parse.h"
    #include <fstream>

    int main()
    {
        fstream OutFile("allheaders.txt", ios::in);
        string str;
        vector<string> headersFile;
        int m = 0;
        while(!OutFile.eof())
        {
            m++;
        OutFile >> str;
        headersFile.push_back(str);
        str.clear();
        }
        cout << m;
        system("pause");
    }
```

Не знаю в чем проблема. Пишу на VS2012 на windows 10. Спасибо.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать)

Comment: но проблема не в этом была, а в том что надо указывать полный путь к файлу например: D:\\allheaders.txt

Comment: А можна ли обойти это и писать только файл?

Comment: @Max_Advanced исполняемый файл положите в одну директорию с текстовым, и указывайте только его название.

Comment: я так уже делал. программа просто не записывает в строку ничего, как будто файл пустой.

Comment: @Max_Advanced Вы точно послушали совета _Abyx_ ведь оговоренная вами проблема как раз описана в его ссылке? Т.е. требуется сначала сделать хотя бы одну операцию чтения прежде чем делать проверку на `eof()` (а лучше вообще написать `while(OutFile >> str)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
   ifstream inputFile("allheaders.txt");
   if (inputFile.is_open())
   {
      string str;
      vector<string> headersFile;
      for (int m = 0; inputFile >> str; ++m)
      {
         headersFile.push_back(str);
         cout << m << endl;
      }
   }
   system("pause");
}
```

Как уже сказали в комментариях, применять метод `eof()` до первой операции чтения бессмысленно (всегда вернет `false`). За счет метода `is_open()` вы легко сможете проверить открылся ли ваш файл вообще, а затем воспользоваться `operator >>`, либо процедурой `std::getline` (подробнее можете прочитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-while-input-stream-eof)).

Сам же файл `allheaders.txt` подложите, например, в каталог с файлами исходного кода (а вообще, директория поиска таких файлов зависит от настроек вашего проекта), либо прямо в коде пропишите полный/относительный путь к файлу, например: `ifstream inputFile("./debug/allheaders.txt");`

Comment: Вы бы ещё пояснили автору, что, в общем случае, так строки читать нельзя. Сдаётся мне, он так не специально читает, а от незнания.