# Подсчёт символов в файле C++

Tags: c++, файлы

Только начал изучать использование файлов в C++, столкнулся с такой проблемой: при выполнении следующего кода в выводе всегда дублируется последний символ из .txt, а я не понимаю, с чем это связано

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream f;
    f.open("book.txt");
    f << "435\njfh dh3";
    f.close();

    char a;
    ifstream r;
    r.open("book.txt");
    while (!r.eof()) {
        r >> a;
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    r.close();
    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Выводит 4 3 5 j f h d h 3 3. Так же меня путает ещё то, что если захочу вывести слова, а не символы (поменяю *char a;* на *char a[255];* или *string a;*), то выводятся слова без повторений, ни одного символа, а тем более массива не дублируется - 435 jfh dh3.
Так же хотел бы спросить, как можно посчитать такие символы, как пробел, \n и тп?

Comment: не пропускать пробелы можно, используя `r >> std::noskipws;`

Comment: Дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421083

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите - вы добрались до конца файла, но *не попытались его считать*. Признак конца файла обнаруживается только при попытке чтения за концом файла!

Т.е. `while` у вас прошел нормально, а `r >> a` - нет. Но `a`-то вы все равно выводите!...

Действуйте так:

```
while( r >> a ) cout << a;
```

`r >> a` при успешно считанном `a` вернет `true` (не совсем так, но для нашего рассмотрения - неважно).

Если вам нужно читать все символы именно как символы из бинарного файла - лучше использовать функцию `get()` - `a = r.get()`.

Comment: Наверное, если `char c;`, то все же лучше использовать `r.get(c)`