# Измерение размера файла в С++ используя fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

В моей задаче понадобилось проверить размер файла, порыскав на форумал собрал функцию `is_Empty`, но так выходит, что после проверки размера файла не могу его нормально прочитать. Чтение из файла произвожу при помощи `fin >>` в цикле while при помощи eof, eof читает нормально, т.е. цикл работает, но никаких данных из файла я не получаю.
Где может скрываться ошибка?

```
bool is_Empty(const char*name)
{
    fstream fi; fi.open(name);
    long file_size;
    fi.seekg(0, ios::end);
    file_size = fi.tellg();
    fi.close();
    if (file_size == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
void read(const char *namefile)
{
    int i(0);
    if (is_Empty(namefile))
    {
        cout << "Pust"; return;
    }
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(namefile);
while(!fin.eof()){
//Тут дальше идёт код считывания из файла
```

Comment: "while(!fin.eof()){//Тут дальше идёт код считывания из файла" который наверняка будет неправильным. Вообще зачем нужна эта проверка?

Comment: дело в том, что до того момента, как написал проверку всё шло отлично, проверка нужна (условие такое). Если вас устроит, то код дальше приблизительно такой : char z; fin >> z; И значение Z как задаётся при моздании переменной, таким оно и остаётся

Comment: А зачем она нужна, если шло отлично?

Comment: Если даже проверять таким методом, то можно было и покороче...
`{ ifstream fi(name); fi.seekg(0,ios::end); return fi.tellg()==0; }` Но по-хорошему, надо еще обязательно проверить, открылся ли файл.

Comment: По поводу проверки спросите моего преподавателя, а вот на счёт открытия он открывается, я просто этот кусок кода выкинул, сюда не вставлял.

Comment: Ну у своего преподавателя условие задачи спросите Вы сами. А здесь изложите его (условие) корректно. А если Вы вырвали из контекста задачи только часть ее и хотите получить ответ на всю задачу, то не надо людей "посылать" к преподавателю.

Comment: И приведите 1. код того, что после while, 2. содержимое файла (хотя бы начало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операция открывания/закрывания файла довольно дорогостоящая, лучше без этого обойтись:

```
bool isEmpty( std::ifstream &f )
{
    char c;
    f >> c;
    if( !f ) return true;
    f.seekg( 0, ios::beg );
    return false;
}

void read( const char *namefile)
{
    int i(0);
    std::ifstream fin( namefile );
    if( isEmpty( fin ) ) {
        cout << "Pust"; 
        return;
    }
    while(!fin.eof()){ ...
```

Два момента. Если знаете имя файла сразу, то объект `std::ifstream` лучше сразу инициализировать, а не вызывать отдельно `open()`. Второе, судя по `while( !fine.eof() )` с чтением у вас тоже не все в порядке. Детали можно посмотреть здесь - [Почему считается что неправильно писать while (!input_stream.eof())?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-while-input-stream-eof)

Answer (score 0):

Можно считать количество символов в файле, а поскольку один символ равен одному байту, то несложно написать подобный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

size_t ByteOfFile(const string path){
    ifstream file(path.c_str()); // файл
    size_t s = 0; // счетчик символов

    while (!file.eof()) { // пока не достигнут конец файлв
        file.get();       // читать по одному символу
        s++;              // и увеличивать счетчик
    }

    file.close(); // обязательно закрыть

    s--; // убираем лишнюю итерацию

    return s; // вернуть число символов/байтов
}

int main(){
    cout << "file size " << ByteOfFile("C:\\test.txt") << " bytes" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

файл **test.txt** :

```
123
456
789
```

**вывод:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]