# Как правильно записать список из файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Не могу придумать решение. Есть у меня определенный двухсвязный список:

```
struct Tourism {
    string country;
    int number_of_vouchers;
    float cost_of_voucher;
    string hotel_name;
    int hotel_status;
    int tour_duration;
};

struct List {
    Tourism tourism;
    List * prev;
    List * next;
};
```

есть файл `list.txt`

```
Spain
100
12.3
Madrid
4
12

Ukrain
120
100
Odessa
5
5 и т.д.
```

Как мне правильно пройтись по файлу и записать, все данные в список?
Допустим запись я делаю так.

```
begin = new List;
    begin->prev = NULL;
    fin>>begin->tourism.country;
    fin>>begin->tourism.number_of_vouchers;
    fin>>begin->tourism.cost_of_voucher;
    fin>>begin->tourism.hotel_name;
    fin>>begin->tourism.hotel_status;
    fin>>begin->tourism.tour_duration;
    begin->next = NULL;
```

Но для каждого нового элемента списка прописывать по новому этот же код глупо. Нужно создать какой то цикл, для прохода по файлу, который будет записывать данные. Как его сделать, не знаю.

Comment: `struct list_head { List *first, *last} head = {0, 0}; List *t; while(t = get_list_elem(fin)) add_to_list(&head, t);` Ну, а в `get_list_elem()` размещаете Ваш код, возвращающий `begin` или 0, если читать больше нечего. С `add_to_list()`, надеюсь, справитесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ж пишете на C++? Вот и давайте сделаем нормальный потоковый ввод.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Tourism
{
    string country;
    int number_of_vouchers;
    float cost_of_voucher;
    string hotel_name;
    int hotel_status;
    int tour_duration;
};

istream& operator >> (istream& s, Tourism& t)
{
    return s >> t.country
             >> t.number_of_vouchers
             >> t.cost_of_voucher
             >> t.hotel_name
             >> t.hotel_status
             >> t.tour_duration;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<Tourism> v;
    fstream s { тут имя файла };

    Tourism t;
    while (s >> t)
        v.push_back(t);
}
```

И не пользуйтесь самописными контейнерами с риском ошибиться.

---

**Обновление**:

Приведённое выше решение правильно работает лишь если в строках нет пробелов. При наличии пробелов `s >> t.country` считывает лишь до первого пробела. Дело в том, что чтение строки работает до пробельного символа, а не до конца строки, так что вычитать всю строку не так просто.

Проблема ещё и в том, что мы не можем переключиться на использование `getline` для `t.country`: `getline` и потоковый ввод через `>>` не дружат между собой. Ввод через `>>` игнорирует стартовые пробельные символы, и оставляет финальный `\n` в строке, а `getline` — нет, поэтому при их перемешке работать код не будет.

Решение, которое обычно предлагается — поменять для нашего потока `s` то, что он считает пробельным символом. Если мы скажем ему, что пробелом является только `\n`, то он будет читать строки до конца!

Для этого необходимо следующее заклинание:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    fstream s { тут имя файла };

    // заведём пустую таблицу категорий символов    
    ctype<char>::mask mask[ctype<char>::table_size] = {};
    // обозначим `\n` как пробельный символ
    mask['\n'] = ctype_base::space;
    // объясним потоку, что он должен пользоваться этой таблицей
    s.imbue(locale(s.getloc(), new ctype<char>(mask)));

    vector<Tourism> v;
    Tourism t;
    while (s >> t)
        v.push_back(t);
}
```

Теперь код работает.

---

Возможно, более простой идеологически вариант — читать всё через `getline` и отказаться от `>>` для ввода. Для конвертации полученной строки в значение используем, как обычно, `istringstream`. Код получается немного менее изящным, зато простым и прямолинейным (что не так уж и плохо):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct Tourism
{
    string country;
    int number_of_vouchers;
    float cost_of_voucher;
    string hotel_name;
    int hotel_status;
    int tour_duration;
};

istream& getrecord(istream& s, Tourism& t)
{
    string line;

    // пропускаем пустые строки
    while (line == "" && getline(s, line))
        ;
    // если поток в хорошем состоянии, мы прочитали непустую строку
    if (s)
        t.country = line;

    if (getline(s, line))
        istringstream(line) >> t.number_of_vouchers;
    if (getline(s, line))
        istringstream(line) >> t.cost_of_voucher;
    if (getline(s, line))
        t.hotel_name = line;
    if (getline(s, line))
        istringstream(line) >> t.hotel_status;
    if (getline(s, line))
        istringstream(line) >> t.tour_duration;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<Tourism> v;
    fstream s { тут имя файла };

    Tourism t;
    while (getrecord(s, t))
        v.push_back(t);
}
```

Магия с локалью не понадобилась.

Comment: это курсовая. векторами пользоваться нам ещё рано. а вот идею с перегрузкой оператора, переделаю под себя. должно сработать. спасибо, мысль уловил.

Comment: @V.Rotenberh: Ах, курсовая, ну тогда да, ограничения. Обратите внимание на условие выхода из цикла, оно несамоочевидно.

Comment: вот с его пока ещё не могу понять. Не подскажите как по другому сделать условие проверки выхода из цикла, на основе списка. Если s >> указателя на список?

Comment: @V.Rotenberh: А вот это условие как раз очень стоит понять. Подумайте над тем, какого типа выражение `s >> t`. Другие пути возможны, но это против стиля C++. Так что потратьте время и освойте эту логику — пригодится (не для курсовой, для работы).

Comment: @V.Rotenberh: Почитайте, например, вот этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/421084/10105. Там описывается именно то, что нужно.

Comment: прочитал, разобрался. С этим всё ясно. Подвяз в перегрузке операторов. А как перегрузить оператор для объекта списка непосредственно. Что в параметрах должно быть?

Comment: @V.Rotenberh: Не вполне понимаю — вы ж и перегружаете `<<` для объекта типа `Tourism`. А как именно вы хотите?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39456/discussion-between-v-rotenberh-and-vladd).