# Программа, которая считает количество пробелов, точек, запятых в файле

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер!
Необходимо написать программу, которая считает количество пробелов, точек и запятых в файле. Я попыталась сделать это, создав массив типа char, но преподаватель не одобрил)) 
Мне не совсем понятно, как можно выполнить это задание, не создавая массива, а используя ifstream/ofstream и связанные с ними функции. Можно ли как-нибудь спасти мою программу, внеся незначительные изменения, чтобы она работала правильно?)) А то переписывать всё заново как-то не очень хочется..((
Заранее спасибо!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char a[1000];
cout << "Enter your text: " << endl;
gets (a);
int spc = 0, dt = 0, km = 0;
int lng = strlen(a);

for (int d = 0; d < lng; d++)
{
    if (a[d] == ',') km++;
}

for (int c = 0; c < lng; c++)
{
    if (a[c] == '.') dt++;
}

for (int b = 0; b < lng; b++)
{
    if (a[b] == ' ') spc++;
}

if (spc >= 1)
{
cout << "The number of spaces in the text is: " << endl << spc << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "There are no spaces in the text" << endl;
}

if (dt >= 1)
{
cout << "The number of dots in the text is: " << endl << dt << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "There are no dots in the text" << endl;
}

if (km >= 1)
{
cout << "The number of commas in the text is: " << endl << km << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "There are no commas in the text" << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Если хочется меньше кода, то `strsep()` твой друг.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
    size_t km = 0, dt = 0, spc = 0;
    if(file.is_open()){
        std::string line;
        while(getline(file, line)){
            km += count(line.begin(), line.end(), ' ');
            dt += count(line.begin(), line.end(), ',');
            spc += count(line.begin(), line.end(), '.');
        }
    }else{
        std::cerr << "Erroe file open!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << km << " " << dt << " " << spc << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Так каждый символ считается по отдельности.

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно можно. Например так:

```
    int x;
    while ( (x = cin.get()) != -1)
        switch (x){
           case ',': km++; break;
           case '.': dt++; break;
           case ' ': spc++; break;
        }
```

Код примерно, точно доработаете под свои требования.

Comment: Почему не просто `char x; while (cin.get(x)) ...` ?

Comment: @avp вроде бы тогда букву Ё не читает чтоли... Привычка)

Comment: Проверил (даже в винде g++ 3.4.5). Нормально читает до конца файла и `ёЁ `и `яЯ`

Answer (score 1):

[Совсем незначительные изменения:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MlHs1lthZumXatak)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::noskipws(std::cin);
    std::cout << std::count_if(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
                     std::istream_iterator<char>(), 
                     [](auto ch) -> bool { return ::strchr( ",. ", ch); }) << "\n";
}
```

Это если нужно общее кол-во.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *fileName = "C:/avia.txt";
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    std::map<char, int> chars;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        char ch;
        file.get(ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
        case ' ':
        case '.':
        case ',':
            chars[ch]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(auto it = chars.begin(); it != chars.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "Char: '" << it->first << "' count: " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421083/10105

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
    size_t col = 0;
    if(file.is_open()){
        std::string characters{" .,"};
        std::string line;
        while(getline(file, line)){
            std::string::size_type pos = 0;
            while((pos = line.find_first_of(characters, pos)) != std::string::npos)
                ++col, ++pos;
        }
    }else{
        std::cerr << "Error open file!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << col << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Полный вариант, который считает общее количество символов " ,."