# Ввод в экспоненциальной форме записи

Tags: c++, c++11

Нужно считать целые числа, среди них есть записанные в экспоненциальном виде, есть ли способ их пометить как не правильные и пропустить, без обработки чисел как строки и переводом в число опять. Пробовал считывать в double и проверять остаток, но его может и не быть, зависит от числа, а в int записывает округлённый результат. Есть флаг fixed, но на cin он, конечно-же не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Если заранее неизвестно, в каких фиксированных позициях располагаются "неправильные" числа, то пропустить их автоматически не получится. Читать придется именно строки и затем анализировать/переводить их в числа дополнительным вызовом какой-нибудь функции перевода.

Однако не совсем понятно, почему вы говорите о переводе "в число *опять*". Никакого "опять" тут не будет - читаем строку и переводим ее в число ровно один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим все числа записаны в одну строку, не знаю какой разделительный символ между ними, если пробел то просто считываем строку, если нет, то используем getline. Если строк много, то снова getline, только с другим разделительным символом

input - входной поток

```
string s;
int x;
while(!input.eof()){
    intput>>s;//строка до разделителя
    stringstream ss(s);
    ss>>x;
    if (!ss.eof()) {// не дошли при парсинге инта до конца строки
        //значит x отметаем
        report_error(s);
    }
    do_smth(x);
}
```

в итоге: если на входе было 123 2, в результате будет 123, 2;
если было 123e2 2, на первой итерации s=123e2, x=123, ss.eof()=false

Comment: "Цикул с предусловием `!eof` - практически всегда ошибка в С и С++"

Comment: пример пожалста, вот [тут](https://ideone.com/7XpKjZ) например работает

Comment: Во входной файл добавьте пробел после последней `2`. И сразу же в выводе магическим образром появится лишняя `2`.

Comment: Это даже попало в наш FAQ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421083/10105

Comment: тогда придется проверять input.good() после считывания s
или использовать результат операции input>>s? означает ли это, что не важно, дошли мы  до конца файла или нет?
вобщем пока исправил до [такого](https://ideone.com/dEqx1r) вида

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение с использованием printf, он считывает только число, после этого можно проверить следующий символ, если это разделитель - число int, если нет - не целое число.