# Не читается слово из заданного файла

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

Не читает слова из файла "`input.txt`" (24 строчка). Если `getline` заменить на `fin >> word`, то ничего не изменится. В чем проблема?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string wordsChecker(string checkWord) // функция для проверки слова
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkWord.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (checkWord[i] && checkWord[i + 1] == 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Ж', 'З', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ')
        {
            return checkWord;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string word;
    ifstream fin("input.txt"); // текстовый файл для чтения
    while (!fin.eof()) // цикл для вывода и получения слов
    {
        getline(fin, word);
        cout << wordsChecker(word) << ' ';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-вторых, вот так- `while (!fin.eof())` - вы будете делать одно лишнее (неверное) чтение. А во-первых, вы проверяли, например, что файл открыт? в коде этого нет. Попробуйте для начала убедиться, что файл открыт, а после считывания просто выводить `word` без обработки - для начала.

Comment: @Harry да, файл открыт. Но значение `word` пусто при чтении. Несмотря на это вместо слов которые проходят проверку выводятся вообще все слова которые есть в файле.

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь проверить условием `checkWord[i] && checkWord[i + 1] == 'б', 'в', 'г',...`? Оно всегда истинно. И что должна вернуть функция `wordsChecker`, если `checkWord.length()` будет равно 1?

Comment: `wordsChecker` возвращает мусор и вызывает неопределенное поведение. `checkWord[i + 1] == 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д'` не сравнивает с каждой буквой из списка.

Comment: E вас написано четко "не читает слова". Т.е. не выполняется чтение  из файла. Как могут выводиться "все слова, которые есть в файле", если вы пишете "Не читает слова из файла"??!! Вы уж определитесь... И задайте вопрос **ТОЧНО**!

Comment: @Harry ошибся. Должны выводиться слова где есть две гласные буквы подряд, но на практике он выводит любое слово.  Значит проблема в `checkWord[i] && checkWord[i + 1] == 'б', 'в', 'г',...`? Как тогда по другому написать эту строчку чтобы проверка выполнялась корректно?

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko, я не писал, что `checkWord.length()` всегда будет равно `1`, я спросил, что по-вашему произойдёт, если `checkWord.length()` будет равно `1`? Что по-вашему вернёт функция в такой ситуации?

Comment: Относительно `eof` почитайте: [Почему считается что неправильно писать while (!input_stream.eof())?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-while-input-stream-eof)

Comment: @wololo ничего не вернет? Не будет захода в цикл `for`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, захода в цикл не произойдёт. А значит оператор `return` выполнен не будет. В языке C++ если тип возвращаемого функцией значения отличен от `void`, то она обязана вернуть некоторое значение при помощи оператора `return`. Если это требование не выполнено, то может произойти всё что угодно.То есть, в вашем случае, в ситуациях, когда цикл `for` не выполнится ни разу, произойдёт что-то нехорошее, например, программа аварийно завершиться. Таким образом, вы должны предусмотреть ситуацию, когда цикл `for` не выполнится ни разу.

Comment: @wololo если написать `return 0`, то появится ошибка. Что тогда надо написать чтобы он возвращал слово только при правильной проверке?

Comment: Ну, тип возвращаемого функцией значения — `string`, а значит и возвращать нужно либо объект типа `string`, либо нечто, что может быть приведено к этому типу. Можно, например, написать `return string();`, или `return "bad_word";` Однако, по смыслу, функция предназначена для проверки того, удовлетворяет ли входная строка некоторому критерию или нет, и поэтому, возможно, лучшим решением будет поступить также как и в ответе Harry: сменить тип возвращаемого значения на `bool` и возвращать `true` или `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, я бы делал примерно так (не тестировал, для изложения идеи):

```
bool check(const string& word)
{
    static char * vowels = "аеиоуэюяАЕИОУЭЮЯ";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; ++i)
        if (strchr(vowels,word[i]) && strchr(vowels,word[i+1]))
            return true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string word;
    ifstream fin("input.txt"); // текстовый файл для чтения
    while(fin>>word)
        if (check(word)) cout << word << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Отдельный вопрос с кодировками, конечно... Для начала я бы подрессировал программу на английских текстах :)

Comment: Спасибо! ;) Пожалуй самый оптимальный код.