# Не возможно выйти из цикла c++

Tags: c++, fstream

Вот такой кусок кода:

```
fstream Results;
Results.open(path2, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
if (!Results.is_open())
{
    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << n;
}
else
{
    int newM;
    char rE;
    int gresult = rarr[0] + rarr[1] + rarr[2];
    while (!Results.eof())
    {
        Results >> newM;
        if (newM == gresult)
        {
            Results >> rE;
            cout << rE << n;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Results.close();
```

Массив и путь, говорю сразу, правильные.
Однако написанное в файле не выводится, но и не выдаёт ошибки.
Проверка с помощью отладчика показала, что не выходит из цикла while.
Пожалуйста , объясните почему.`введите сюда код`

Comment: [Посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-while-input-stream-eof)

Comment: (Закрывая пока глаза на неправильное использование `eof`) И что же за значения читаются из файла? Что показал отладчик по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном вопросе [why is while feof file always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) написано, что цикл вида:

```
while( !file.eof() )
```

почти всегда неверно. Вам следует поменять условие цикла на:

```
while ( Results >> newM ) {
  ....
}
```

Это не ошибка, но не имеет смысла создавать файловый поток без параметров и следующей же строкой открывать его, эти параметры можно просто передать в конструктор:

```
fstream Results(path2, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас не `int` в файле.

Ошибка чтения при [неверном условии завершения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) приводит к тому, что вы пытаетесь читать какую-то ерунду - не целое число - вечно...

```
while (!Results.eof())
{
    Results >> newM;
    ...
}
```

Получается так:

Была попытка чтения за концом файла? Нет? Тогда читаем `int`. Не удалось? Остаемся на том же месте, выставляем состояние файла `fail`.
Идем к условию цикла. Была попытка чтения за концом файла? Нет? Тогда читаем `int`? нет, файл в состоянии `fail`.
Так что идем к условию цикла. Была попытка чтения за концом файла? Нет? Тогда читаем `int`? нет, файл в состоянии `fail`.
Так что идем к условию цикла. Была попытка чтения за концом файла? Нет? Тогда читаем `int`? нет, файл в состоянии `fail`. Так что идем...