# ifstream.get() не считывает ни одного символа после переноса строки

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, istream

Есть код, который находит позиции всех вхождений содержимого `find_it.txt` в файле `find_here.txt`. Всё работает, однако, он игнорирует все символы после переноса строки.

Минимальный код для воспроизведения ошибки.

```
ifstream find_here("find_here.txt");
ifstream find_it("find_it.txt");

const int buffer_size = 1e+5;
while(!find_here.eof()) {
    char temp_segment[buffer_size];
    find_here.get(&temp_segment[0], buffer_size);
}
```

find_here.txt

```
TEST
V CHASCHAH YUGA ZHIL BI CZITRUZ?
YEAH BABE, BUT FALSHIVIY EXEMPLYAR
```

find_it.txt

```
V CHASCHAH YUGA ZHIL BI CZITRUZ?
YEAH BABE, BUT FALSHIVIY EXEMPLYAR
```

В `find_here.txt` ни считывается ничего далее первой строки - `TEST`.
А так же код уходит в бесконечный цикл, т.к. файл ещё не считан полностью.
Но файл не может считаться полностью, он перестаёт считывать перенос строки и далее.

Как сделать так, чтобы переносы считывались так же, как и простые символы?

Comment: Так именно так и работает `get` - читает до конца строки. Хотите читать все подряд - используйте `read`, а не `get`. Ну и как обычно: цикл с предусловием `!eof` - практически всегда ошибка.

Comment: @AnT И правда. Спасибо за совет с read, теперь всё работает.

Comment: Но почему цикл с предусловием !eof() это практически всегда ошибка?

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко, почитайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-while-input-stream-eof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем разборки :)

```
const int buffer_size = 1e+5;
```

Вам лень написать 2 лишних символа и вы предпочитаете преобразование типа `double` и `int`? Зачем?

```
while(!find_here.eof())
```

Уж сколько раз [твердили миру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)... Прочтите еще раз, как писать условие верно.

```
find_here.get(&temp_segment[0], buffer_size);
```

Логично. Считывание строки [до `\n`, как и написано](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). Но там же написано, что этот самый `\n` не считывается и не отбрасывается. Вот ваш код и пытается читать пустую строку до полного обалдения... Отбросьте этот символ - например,

```
find_here.get(&temp_segment[0], buffer_size);
find_here.get();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Документацию действительно стоит лучше читать. Однако, проблему с `get` я решил заменой `get` на `read`, который не имеет свойства считывания только до `\n`.

Comment: Так же да, мне не лень написать 2 лишних символа, но я считаю запись `1e+5` более понятной и приятной на глаз, чем `100000`. Не думаю, что это преобразование влияет хоть как-то на скорость программы, тем более, что `buffer_size` есть константа.

Comment: На скорость - не влияет, но лишнее предупреждение...

Comment: У меня никаких предупреждений нет.

Comment: Включите предупреждения, они часто говорят умные вещи. В VC++ оно выглядит как `warning C4244: инициализация: преобразование "double" в "int", возможна потеря данных`

Comment: Я пользуюсь GСС (MinGW) компилятором и включил все флаги с предупреждениями, что есть. Конкретно такого предупреждения при компиляции не выводится.