# В файле дописать к каждому слову текст

Tags: c++

Имеется файл input.txt с таким содержимым: qwer qwe qwe qwerty.
Собственно вопрос: Как дописать к каждому слову в скобочках какой-то текст?
На выходе нужно получить: qwer(123) qwe(123) qwe(123) qwerty(123)
Реализовать на c++

Comment: Читайте и пишите в другой файл, а потом удалите первый и переименуйте второй, или, если слов не слишком много - читайте их в память, а потом перезаписывайте в тот же файл заново...

Answer (score -2):

Я бы делал так: учитывал бы весь файл
string tmp;
vector str;

```
while(!file.eof())
    {
           strong s;
          getline(file, tmp);
                for(int i= 0; I < tmp.size(); i++)
                     (
                          s += tmp[i];
                          if(tmp[i] == ' ')
                               {
                                     str.push_back(s);
                                      s.clear();
```

}
}

Теперь у нас есть вектор, слов. Можножно теперь работать с каждым словом по отдельности. Ну и когда все изменения сделаны, записать весь в чистый файл

Comment: При таком подходе не нужно читать и разбирать строки. Достаточно читать файл по словам -- `while (file >> s) str.push_back(s);`

Comment: Я просто не был уверен что таким образом можно дойти до конца файла. Плохо знаком с фстрим)

Comment: [Почему считается что неправильно писать while (!input_stream.eof())?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-while-input-stream-eof)

Comment: А вот этого не знал. Спасибо за информацию

Comment: @Максим, imho желательно что-то советовать остальным, только если сами уверены, что хорошо разбираетесь в вопросе

Comment: @avp Сколько я это использовал, ни разу не подводил, поэтому и был уверен. Но ваш совет приму на заметку