# Отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "getline"

Tags: c++, файлы

Имеется такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru");

    ofstream FILE1("FILE1.txt", ios_base::app | ios_base::in);

    int numAmount;
    cout << "Введите количество строк: ";
    cin >> numAmount;

    char line[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < numAmount; i++) {
        cin >> line;
        FILE1 << line;
        FILE1 << "\n";
    }



    ofstream FILE2("FILE2.txt", ios_base::app);

    string buff;
    while (!FILE1.eof()) {
        getline(FILE1, buff);
    }


}
```

Выбивает такую ошибку:

> отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "getline",
>   соответствующие списку аргументов

Все пишут, что нужно подключить `<string>`, так и сделал, но это не решило проблему, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream` - поток вывода, `ifstream` - поток ввода, `getline` принимает первым аргументом поток ввода. `while (!FILE1.eof())` некорректная конструкция: [Почему считается что неправильно писать while (!input_stream.eof())?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421083/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-while-input-stream-eof)